# 1 to many relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, relationship, one-to-many

I have the follow two tables:

Departments(Id, Description)

Employees(Id, Name, DepartmentId)

My realtionship between this tables is: one employee is a member of one department and one deparment has many employees.

To be sure that every employee has a department assigned, I simply set the column "DepartmentId" as not null.

But how can I be sure, there is no department which has no employees assigned? Because the meaning of "one to many" is: every single department has at least one employee.

Thanks and best regards

MB

Comment: The relation is `1:n` and by its definition 1 department may have many employees or none at all. If a department should always have at least 1 employee how would it be possible to insert a row in the table Departments since at that moment there would not be any employees in that department?

Comment: hey forpas, okay. thank you for your explination

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT Id, Description
FROM Departments d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees e WHERE e.DepartmentId = d.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers.

I was more asking me, is there a way to prevent this.

Because the definition of "one to many" is, there must be at least one. 

And if I have look to the above described model, I implemented this realationship here: 1 to 0..n

Comment: Why do you need to prevent empty departments?

Comment: Becuase the definition of "1 to 1..n" is, that every single depatment need at least one employee. But in my case, I can have departments without any employees. Is there a way I can handel this case by database? Or I have to do this by the application? Thanks MB

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query below to find all the departments that doesn't have any employees registered:

```
SELECT * from departments WHERE departments.id not in(SELECT employees.dep_id from employees GROUP by employees.dep_id)
```